# How to prevent ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python

```
f =open(input("Enter the name of the password file: "),'r') #opens inputed file
lines = f.readlines()
list_=[]
credentials = {}
for line in lines:
        user, pw = line.strip().split(':') # error in this line
        credentials[user] = pw # creates a dict of usernames and passwords
        list_.append(pw) #creates a list of passwords
```

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).

The file should be formatted as `user:password`.
If there is inconsistency in the file, how can I split the username and passwords to ultimately create a dictionary? Do I need to use `.items()`?

Comment: What do you mean by inconsistency in the file? Do you mean one line being usernamepassword (no seperating ':')? Do you want to ignore that line and keep going?

Comment: Please show some sample input which reproduces the error.  `readlines()` is a bad idea because the newlines are retained.

Comment: formatting: code, text, quote

Comment: I am assuming there is a ':' in one of the passwords. The files are too long to examine thoroughly. For example:

Comment: sidzi:abc124
jessijane:93152626427
leveanna:slipknot4
schumiedamani:bebizhayn
berezin:prince
sayquiah:12345678
pengabar:nathan2001
ochayna:rocks
captainzed:adissa
monanga:johneric
bueyvoodoo:ashash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that there is a colon `':'` inside the user name or the password--more likely inside the password. You could ignore the colon and everything after it in the password, truncating it. One way to do that is to use

```
user, pw, *throwaway = line.strip().split(':')
```

If the line is as expected, the variable `throwaway` will be an empty list. If there are extra colons in the line, `throwaway` will be a list of items after the second colon, and you can just ignore it.

The main problem with my solution is that if there is a colon in the user name, the first part of that user name will be treated as the user name and the second part will be treated as the password, with any other parts of the user name ignored together with the password. Given your stated format I do not see any way around that. Another problem is that this prevents a colon from being used in a password.